# $resource GET request address resolution

Tags: angularjs, rest, url

I am following the tutorial on [thinkster.io](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/S2MxGFCO0B/3-communicating-with-a-server-using-a-service-and-resource) and the URL resolution is a bit puzzling for me.

```
app.factory('Post', function($resource){
  return $resource('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseIO.com/posts/:id.json');
});
```

...

```
$scope.posts = Post.get()
```

when I make the GET request from the controller, the URL that gets resolved to:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseIO.com/posts.json
```

The explanation is not good enough for me:

> This sends a get request to our resource url without any parameters (so the ':id' part is ignored) which is where we will be storing our posts.

what happened to `/posts`? I would think that the URL should have been:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseIO.com/posts
```

instead.

This is not because `firebaseIO` redirects the request, because I looked at the HTTP request header in Google Chrome Console. I also looked at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for $Resource, but I do not see an appropriate explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original request, the `post` part isn't missing. What is missing is the `/:id` part.

You get this URL, because you missed the `:id` part. The parts starting with a colon `:` are a parameters which you can supply to the `Post` when making a request.

To supply `id`, use the following syntax:

```
Post.get({id: 'abc'});
```

This would make request to the following URL:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseIO.com/posts/abc.json
```

Comment: I understand your explanation, but the part I do not understand is what happens when it missing. So by default when the parameter is missing and the request type is GET, does it always resolve to the root directory '/' of the given website and the request is made on `posts.json`?

Comment: Oh I get it now. `/:id` including the slash gets omitted.